# How do I show my json array of phone numbers in listview alongside other numbers?

Tags: android, arrays, listview

I get a `JSON Array` from the server that consists of some of the phone contacts on the phone of the person who is using my app. I want these phone numbers to be displayed to the user in a `ListView` as `'Already a contact'`.

The `JSON Array`, called `JsonArrayMatchingContacts`, might be, for example:

```
[{"contact_phonenumber":"+12345678"},{"contact_phonenumber":"+23456789},
{"contact_phonenumber":"+34567890"}]
```

Here's my code, but it's not working. It works for an individual value - for example if I have `if (phoneNumberofContact.equals("+12345678")) etc..` it comes up with `Already a Contact` but I need to have it working for my `JSON Array`. Can you help?

```
                SelectPhoneContact selectContact = new SelectPhoneContact();

                ArrayList<String> MatchingContacts = new ArrayList<String>();
                try {
                    JSONArray Object = new JSONArray(JsonArrayMatchingContacts);
                    for (int x = 0; x < Object.length(); x++) {
                        final JSONObject obj = Object.getJSONObject(x);
                        MatchingContacts.add(obj.getString("contact_phonenumber"));

                    }

                } catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if (phoneNumberofContact.equals(MatchingContacts))
                {

                    phoneNumberofContact= "Already a contact";
                    selectPhoneContacts.add(selectContact);
                } else {
                    selectPhoneContacts.add(selectContact);
                }

                selectContact.setName(name);
                selectContact.setPhone(phoneNumberofContact);
```

Comment: Just wondering would you not have to do the compare (if statement) in the for loop as currently, you are trying to compare against a list. which would never work as it cannot go to the next number in the list

Comment: A little suggestion: pay attention to your naming conventions. It's not usual to start variable names with a capital letter in java. But if you really want to break conventions you should at least be consistent. And it's very confusing to name variable Object because Java already uses this name for a class which is the parent of all classes in java.

Comment: @josef.adamcik Ah, so it's you who gave me the downvote? :) The pc with my code not available at the mo will try your code when it's up again, tx for the answer.

Comment: @CHarris No, I did not downvote your question. Just trying to help you to improve .)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing a string ( phoneNumberofContact ) with a list ( MatchingContacts ).

You should check if the string is contained in the list.

```
if (MatchingContacts.contains( phoneNumberofContact )) {
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  put your if condition in loop..you will get it.try this
   SelectPhoneContact selectContact = new SelectPhoneContact();

            ArrayList<String> MatchingContacts = new ArrayList<String>();
            try {
                JSONArray Object = new JSONArray(JsonArrayMatchingContacts);
                for (int x = 0; x < Object.length(); x++) {
                    final JSONObject obj = Object.getJSONObject(x);
                    if (phoneNumberofContact.equals(MatchingContacts))
            {

                phoneNumberofContact= "Already a contact";
                selectPhoneContacts.add(selectContact);
            } else {
                selectPhoneContacts.add(selectContact);
            }

                }

            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



            selectContact.setName(name);
            selectContact.setPhone(phoneNumberofContact);
```